# sys.path list shows current directory tiwce, is it by design in python ...?

Tags: python, sys.path

I am running simple code below , just to see list of dirs where python looks for module:

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

It shows 0th and 1st index both are same , like below

```
'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\PycharmProjects\\test',
'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\PycharmProjects\\test',
```

I'm not sure why it shows current dir twice.

Comment: Depends on how it got that way, which depends on a lot of details you haven't given. What directory are you in? How are you starting the interpreter? Do you have any PYTHONPATH defined? Are you in a virtualenv? What wrappers, if any, are around your Python interpreter? Is it PyCharm starting your interpreter, or are you doing that by hand? Etc, etc, etc.

Comment: Is it by design that there will *always* be two entries for the current directory? No, absolutely not. Can we confidently tell you why it's happening with only the information given in the question? No, we can't.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, thanks for reply , apologies for not sharing more deatils
1) i am in C:\\Users\\Administrator\\PycharmProjects\\test only 
2) No PYTHONPATH env set on my machine
3) i am using PyCharm editor , so PyCharm starts my interpreter 

simple script written pycharm editor , and run it in pycharm only ( using run button on top right corner)

Comment: I'd suggest starting the interpreter *without* going through pycharm, and comparing results.